# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_role' как исправить?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pip

Вот довольно примитивный кусок кода, взятый с какого-то сайта:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ">", intents = discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Запустился")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    author = message.author
    guild = bot.get_guild('айди')
    role = guild.get_role('айди')
    await author.add_roles(role)

bot.run("токен")

role = guild.get_role('тут айди')
```

Вот ошибка -
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_role'

Почему? Как мне сделать выдачу роли при написании сообщения?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140002/discussion-on-question-by-zix---on-message--pip-discord-py).

Answer (score 0):

`role = guild.get_role("Айди")` (в конце)
находится за пределами on_message, а так же не знает что за guild ему предоставляют.

Answer (score 0):

Советую использовать `discord.utils.get`:

```
    member = message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = 995310762451025940)
```

Далее:

```
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

Answer (score 0):

Передавайте не строку, а именно числовой id так и в `bot.get_guild`, так и в `guild.get_role`. Также у бота должны быть привилегии на сервере, чтобы дать эту роль. Я проверил, у меня всё работает, если проблема сохранилась, она (проблема), скорее всего, состоит в том, какую библиотеку Вы используете и в её версии, я использую py-cord версии V2.3.2